# Basis for the range of the matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

> I did the first part properly and showed that the rank is 2, but putting this matrix into a reduced row echleon form. For the second part, I get the wrong basis vectors simply because of something weird. Look at it :

[image]

---

^^ **Look** at this picture, there is in the reduced echleon form numbers on the right side which are : 1,-15, -17,-6 . **Where did these values come from** O.o the way I did was (I started like) :

$$\left[\begin{array}{cccc|c} 1 & 1 & 5 & 7 & 0\\ 3 & 9 & 17 & 25 & 0 \\ 1 & 7 & 7 & 11&0\\3&6&16&23&0\end{array}\right]$$

Comment: Why do you consider the augmented matrix? Once you know that the range space has dimension two you only need to find two linearly independent vectors in the range space.

Comment: @X Nova, your question's title is incorrect: a matrix is not a vector space and thus has no basis.

Comment: @Timbuc I suppose it is the basis of T.

Comment: @Sjoerd, that also makes no sense: transformations, as matrices, are not spaces.

Comment: @Timbuc Correct, meant that it is a basis of range of T.

Comment: @mfl , but what are those numbers in the answer. They find it using augmented matrix :/ shouldn't it be zeros, how did they get those values

Comment: @Timbuc , shall I rename my question? :) What do you think I should call it ? :)

Comment: @mfl , Thank you so much :D yes I could just tate the corresponding vectors ones I have the rank. But then again , what are those numbers in their first part? How did the examiner put those numbers in the augmented matrix

Comment: @XNova, perhaps "basis for the range of a matrix" of "basis for the row (column) space of a matrix"

Comment: @Timbuc , done :)

Comment: The numbers in the added column can be obtained as $4C_1-3C_2.$ I don't see any reason to consider them just to get the dimension of the range space. It seems that you are studying the compatibility of a linear system.

Comment: @mfl , I don't understand $4C_1 - 4C_2$ , how can this affect the zero side. Because when I write zero column on the right side, whatever operation you do it will still be zero right? :)

Comment: I am not saying this has any effect. I was only trying to explain a possible way to get the numbers on the last column in the augmented matrix.

Comment: @mfl , okayyyyy :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way or obtaining the basis is reducing the transformation matrix and look at the pivot columns. In this case, the pivot numbers are $m1,m2$. Therefore the basis of the transformation are columns $m1,m2$ of $M$, because $m3,m4$ are linear combinations of $m1,m2$.